Cannot get iPhone to accept SCEP/MDM Device Certificate
I'm trying to issue a device certificate (in c# using BouncyCastle) to an iOS device by implementing the SCEP protocol.
No matter what I do I always seem to get the iPhone telling me the SCEP server response is Invalid.
I've looked at other articles on here and nothing helps.
I've condensed it down to as small as I can. I believe what I'm doing is largely correct, but I just can't see what the error could be.
Any help would be much appreciated.
(note: my DEVICE_IDENTITY_CERT_SUBJECT matches the value from my _signingCertificate)
(note2: I think I'm including the correct intermediate and root certs, but I could be mistaken)
public byte[] CreateAndSignDeviceCertificate(PKIMessage msg, AsymmetricKeyParameter _privateKey, X509Certificate _signingCertificate)
    {
    MessageType msgType = msg.MessageType;
    var msgData = msg.Raw;
    string transId = msg.TransactionID;
    Nonce recipientNonce = new Nonce(msg.SenderNonce);
    Nonce senderNonce = Nonce.NextNonce();

    // Load MDM server certificate
    var _mdmServerCertificate = LoadCertificate("mdm.cer"); //same as _signingCertificate

    // Load Apple's intermediate certificate
    var _appleIntermediateCertificate = LoadCertificate("AppleWWDRCAG3.cer");

    // Load Apple's root certificate
    var _appleRootCertificate = LoadCertificate("AppleIncRootCertificate.cer");


    string DEVICE_IDENTITY_CERT_SUBJECT = "UID=XXXXX,CN=MyName,OU=XXXXX,O=MyName,C=US";
    X509ExtensionsGenerator _extensionGenerator = new X509ExtensionsGenerator();

    X509V3CertificateGenerator _certificateGenerator = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
    SecureRandom _secureRandom = new SecureRandom();

    Pkcs10CertificationRequest certReq = new Pkcs10CertificationRequest(msgData);

    AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = certReq.GetPublicKey();

    string algo = "SHA256WithRSA";
    // Set the certificate properties
    _certificateGenerator.SetSerialNumber(new BigInteger(128, _secureRandom));
    _certificateGenerator.SetIssuerDN(new X509Name(DEVICE_IDENTITY_CERT_SUBJECT)); // Issuer is the same as subject for self-signed certificate
    _certificateGenerator.SetSubjectDN(new X509Name(DEVICE_IDENTITY_CERT_SUBJECT));
    _certificateGenerator.SetNotBefore(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
    _certificateGenerator.SetNotAfter(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1));
    _certificateGenerator.SetPublicKey(publicKey);
    _certificateGenerator.SetSignatureAlgorithm(algo);

    // Add extensions
    _certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.BasicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(false));
    _certificateGenerator.AddExtension(X509Extensions.KeyUsage, true, new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.DigitalSignature | KeyUsage.KeyEncipherment));

    // Sign the certificate
    X509Certificate deviceIdentityCert = _certificateGenerator.Generate(new Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Operators.Asn1SignatureFactory(algo, _privateKey));

    //encode cert rep
    // Create the signed attributes
    var signedAttributes = new Asn1EncodableVector();

    // Add TransactionId
    signedAttributes.Add(new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Cms.Attribute(
        new DerObjectIdentifier("2.16.840.1.113733.1.9.7"),
        new DerSet(new DerPrintableString(transId))));

    // Add SenderNonce
    signedAttributes.Add(new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Cms.Attribute(
        new DerObjectIdentifier("2.16.840.1.113733.1.9.5"),
        new DerSet(new DerOctetString(senderNonce.GetEncoded()))));

    // Add RecipientNonce
    signedAttributes.Add(new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Cms.Attribute(
        new DerObjectIdentifier("2.16.840.1.113733.1.9.6"),
        new DerSet(new DerOctetString(recipientNonce.GetEncoded()))));

    // Add PKIStatus
    signedAttributes.Add(new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Cms.Attribute(
        new DerObjectIdentifier("2.16.840.1.113733.1.9.3"),
        new DerSet(new DerPrintableString("0"))));


    // Create CMS signed data generator
    var cmsgenerator = new CmsSignedDataGenerator();

    // Add the signer information
    var certList = new List<X509Certificate>
{
    deviceIdentityCert,          // The certificate being issued
    _signingCertificate,              // The CA certificate (signing certificate)
    _appleIntermediateCertificate, // Apple's Intermediate certificate
    _appleRootCertificate        // Apple's Root certificate
};

    var certStore = X509StoreFactory.Create(
        "Certificate/Collection",
        new X509CollectionStoreParameters(certList));

    // Add the signer information and certificate store
    cmsgenerator.AddSigner(
        _privateKey,
        _signingCertificate, 
        CmsSignedDataGenerator.DigestSha256,
        new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Cms.AttributeTable(signedAttributes),
        null);

    cmsgenerator.AddCertificates(certStore);


    // Generate the signed data
    CmsSignedData signedData = cmsgenerator.Generate(new CmsProcessableByteArray(deviceIdentityCert.GetEncoded()),
            true);
    
    // Create the enveloped data
    var envelopeGenerator = new CmsEnvelopedDataGenerator();
    envelopeGenerator.AddKeyTransRecipient(_signingCertificate);

    var envelopedData = envelopeGenerator.Generate(
            new CmsProcessableByteArray(signedData.GetEncoded()),
            CmsEnvelopedDataGenerator.DesEde3Cbc);

    return envelopedData.GetEncoded();
}

